# set default text to edit text, and hide it when onClick

Tags: android, android-edittext

i want to create edit text with text

> "Enter text, please"
>   But when user click on this editText - this text must be hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myEditText.setHint("Enter text, please");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only to put this line on your XML file

```
android:hint="what you want to show..."
```

Example:

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myEdit" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:hint="Some text"
        android:singleLine="true"
    </EditText>
```

that's all